# How do I see in Google Analytics specific Facebook post exactly bringing me traffic?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, analytics

I would like to see in analytics specific Facebook posts that are bringing traffic to the site. The 'Referrals' doesn't provide this info, but only shows how much traffic came from Facebook.com and m.facebook.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of UTM Parameters.

What Makes Up a UTM Link?

Here’s my link for a test post

```
www.yourwebsite.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=post_name&utm_content=post_content
```

Now let’s break this link down, to understand what each metric means, and what it corresponds to in Google Analytics.

First, there is the “utm_source” value, which translates to the “source” dimension in Google Analytics. This is where traffic is coming from. You can name it whatever you want. In this example, my source is “facebook”

Equally as important is the medium, specifically “utm_medium,” which tells me what type of traffic this is. As this is from social media, I have named it social.

Easily the most important part of the link — “utm_campaign” — is the name of what you’re tracking, for example, “Summer Promotion.” Think of this as another way to roll up all the different posts and sources to see higher-level insights.

The next two metrics — “utm_term” and “utm_content” — are both optional and interchangeable. It’s about personal preference and how granular you want to get with your analysis.

If you don't want to build the URLs manually, you can use [URL Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) from google.

Make sure you paste the full URL in the URL builder so that it populates the correct URL. Also make sure that you paste the whole URL created by URL builder with all UTM parameters on Facebook.

Hope this helps.